# Is it posibile to change the focus for Camera Module V2?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I am using the camera for reading some text and currently, my images look quite blurry[image]

Is it possible to change the focus of the camera?
I am using

> https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/

Comment: This may help... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=217165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible, I did it many times. Sometimes in the camera box there is even a specific tool to rotate the lens included (check if you have it, I experienced that it's not always present). If you don't have a tool take thin pliers and rotate the lens, you can look [here](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/infrared-bird-box/6).

Comment: I am looking for a software solution at first so that to avoid the possibility of destroying the camera by trying to rotate the lens too hard

Comment: Pi camera v2 does not have autofocus, so I don't think it's possible via software.. It's a very simple operation and it's supported by raspberry, they even include a tool for that sometimes.

Comment: It worked out in the end. I have used my sister's tweezers in order to rotate the lens. I was really afraid not to break the camera because from what I have heard they are really fragile. Thank you